# JSON from a url to a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to decode JSON from a hash and I can't find a way to do it. I've used this code:

```
@summoner = 'https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/summoner/by-name/TurtleTown?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
@summoner = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@summoner)
```

but `@summoner` is a url that contains the JSON. How do I get the JSON form the url?

Comment: summoner = 'https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/summoner/by-name/TurtleTown?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    
summoner = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(summoner)

Comment: What? Post it in the answer, please

Answer (score 1):

Some requred libraries are:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
```

You will need to install `json` gem. For more info look [here](https://github.com/flori/json)

First of all perform a get request to given url. And then decode the request response:

```
#convert your link to URI object understandable by Net:HTTP library
uri = URI('https://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/summoner/by-name/TurtleTown?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx')

#perform actual GET request to given uri
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

#convert JSON response into hash if request was successful
data = JSON.parse(response) if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

Comment: I'm getting (undefined method `hostname')

Comment: Try out edited code. I accidentally used newline character in uri string.

Comment: Now I'm getting (end of file reached) after json installed

Comment: try without `if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)`

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the @summoner variable is a string you need to use something to actually make the request (unless you omitted that code). Something like [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).